# Writing a matrix in terms of other matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A, J \in M_8(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ such that $A$ is invertible and $J^3=0$.

Suppose $(A+KJK^{-1})^2=A+KJK^{-1}$ and $\operatorname{rank}(A+KJK^{-1})=4$.

Is it possible to write $K$ in terms of $A$ and $J$?

Expanding yields
$A^2+AKJK^{-1}+KJK^{-1}A+KJ^2K^{-1}= A+KJK^{-1}$.
But from here it seems that I cannot isolate $K$. Is there a way to do this, or is it not possible?

Hints would suffice. Thank you.

Comment: If there is a solution it is not unique: for each $K_1$ that commutes with $A$ the matrix $K_1K$ is also a solution.

Comment: Per ancientmathematician's comment, it means you cannot solve the equation to get an expression for $K$ in terms of $A$ and $J$ - if you could, that would give a unique solution for $K$. Any solution to your problem will not be by symbolic manipulation of the whole matrices.